# In postfix, what's the difference between myhostname and mydomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

I'm trying to set up postfix for the first time. Reading the [basic configuration docs](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#syntax), right off the bat I'm faced with two settings that I cannot understand - `mydomain` and `myhostname`. I've got the simplest possible situation - a single server for a single domain. Let's call it `example.com`. My server serves the webpages for `http://anything.example.com` and I'd like it to receive email for `whatever@example.com` as well. (Sending too, but that will be only for authorized users; I'll come to that later)

So, in this case, what's the difference between `mydomain` and `myhostname`? Or should they both be simply set to `example.com`?

Also of note might be that my DNS provider (I don't host it myself) for some reason didn't allow me to put `example.com` in my `MX` record. That seemed to be more of a quirk of their system however. I have `mail.example.com` set there, but `*.example.com` maps to my IP anyway (in `A` records), so that shouldn't really matter, right?

Answer (score 4):

The crucial part of the documentation for both is the following, as it tells us how they are used.

> `$myhostname` is used as a default value for many other configuration parameters.
>
> `$mydomain` is used as a default value for many other configuration parameters.

To know what you should have in both, consult the output of `postconf`:

```
# postconf -d | grep myhostname
lmtp_lhlo_name = $myhostname
local_transport = local:$myhostname
milter_macro_daemon_name = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = server.example.com
myorigin = $myhostname
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_proxy_ehlo = $myhostname
```

For receiving mail for `example.com` you only need to have it in `mydestination` (or `virtual_alias_domains` etc.) which by default only has `$myhostname` and `localhost.$mydomain`. Notice that because `mydestination` can be configured to include plain `example.com` (or the variable `$mydomain` containing it), there's no need to have `$myhostname = example.com`. The final destination addresses are not directly based on these variables i.e. it doesn't limit the domains you can accept mail for.

On the other hand, `$myhostname` is used in `smtpd_banner` and `smtp_helo_name`. As [RFC 5321, 4.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.1) explains, this should be the *fully-qualified domain name* (FQDN) of the SMTP client (i.e. your server). Some receiving MTAs may validate that the `HELO` hostname matches the `PTR` record for the IP address, a mismatch causing additional spam score or in worst case even rejection. Therefore, it's recommended to **match `$myhostname` with whatever there is in the `PTR` record**, and check that the `PTR` has a corresponding `A` record.

Additionally, if you wish to receive mail for `user@somethingelse.example.com`, the `*.example.com. A` DNS record alone isn't enough (despite it gets used if there's no `MX` records), but you need to have it listed in your `mydestination`, too.

Answer (score 3):

myhostname is the fully qualified domain name.  mydomain, is the domain you are using for your email.

From the docs

> **myhostname (default: see "postconf -d" output)**
>
> The internet hostname of this mail system. The default is to use the
>   fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) from gethostname(), or to use the
>   non-FQDN result from gethostname() and append ".$mydomain".
>   $myhostname is used as a default value for many other configuration
>   parameters.
>
> Example:
>
> myhostname = host.example.com
>
> **mydomain (default: see "postconf -d" output)**
>
> The internet domain name of this mail system. The default is to use
>   $myhostname minus the first component, or "localdomain" (Postfix 2.3
>   and later). $mydomain is used as a default value for many other
>   configuration parameters.
>
> Example:
>
> mydomain = domain.tld

- http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydomain
- http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname

Comment: But... I don't have a separate hostname. The box _is_ `example.com`. There are no other hosts and there will never be any other hosts. This box and this box alone responds to any subdomains that exists and ever will exist for `example.com`, as well as `example.com` itself without a subdomain. What do I do in this case?

Comment: If you are on the box and you use `hostname -f` what do you get?   That is your fqdn. 
 That is almost certainly not `example.com`?  But you don't have to use that name.  You could also use something arbitrary like `mail.example.com`.

Comment: What value to put if having multiple domains ?

Answer (score 0):

myhostname is the hostname of the postfix server installed. domain name is the SMTP server domain configured.